# Add custom parameters to a programm called by wofi

Tags: brave

I am using `wofi` with `swaywm`.

I want to use the Wofi `drun` menu to launch the Brave Browser. Sadly Brave doesn't support wayland by default so I have to add these parameters to make it work

```
--enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

Is there a way to configure wofi to call

```
/usr/bin/brave --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

instead of just `/usr/bin/brave`?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify desktop file `brave-browser.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications/` then append `--enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland --gtk-version=4` to all lines `Exec` like:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/brave --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland --gtk-version=4
```